# When are placeholders necessary?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Every TensorFlow example I've seen uses placeholders to feed data into the graph. But my applications work fine without placeholders. According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data), using placeholders is the "best practice", but they seem to make the code unnecessarily complex.

Are there any occasions when placeholders are absolutely necessary?

Comment: Can you show an example of where you application works fine without placeholders?

Answer (score 3):

> According to the documentation, using placeholders is the "best practice"

Hold on, this quote is out-of-context and could be misinterpreted. Placeholders are the best practice *when feeding data through `feed_dict`*.

Using a placeholder makes the intent clear: this is an input node that needs feeding. Tensorflow even provides a `placeholder_with_default` that *does not* need feeding — but again, the intent of such a node is clear. For all purposes, a `placeholder_with_default` does the same thing as a `constant` — you can indeed feed the `constant` to change its value, but is the intent clear, would that not be confusing? I doubt so.

There are other ways to input data than feeding and AFAICS all have their uses.

Answer (score 2):

A **placeholder** is a promise to provide a value later.
Simple example is to define two placeholders a,b and then an operation on them like below .

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b  # + provides a shortcut for tf.add(a, b)
```

`a,b` are not initialized and contains no data Because they were defined as placeholders.

Other approach to do same is to define variables `tf.Variable`  and in this case you have to provide an initial value when you declare it.
like :

```
tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

or

```
tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

And this solution has two drawbacks

- Performance wise that you need to do one extra step with calling
  initializer however these variables are updatable .
- in some cases you do not know the initial values for these variables 
  so you have to define it as a placeholder

**Conclusion** :

- use `tf.Variable` for trainable variables such as weights (W) and biases (B) for your model or when Initial values are required  in
  general.
- `tf.placeholder`  allows you to create operations and build computation graph, without needing the data. In TensorFlow
  terminology, we then feed data into the graph through these
  placeholders.

Comment: Small correction, when initial values are required it's probably wise to use `tf.constant` if you don't want the training to change the value

Comment: @OferSadan yes you are right , but i did not mention that because i were mainly comparing between variables and placeholders .

Answer (score 0):

I really like Ahmed's answer and I upvoted it, but I would like to provide an alternative explanation that might or might not make things a bit clearer.

One of the significant features of Tensorflow is that its operation graphs are compiled and then executed outside of the original environment used to build them. This allows Tensorflow do all sorts of tricks and optimizations, like distributed, platform independent calculations, graph interoperability, GPU computations etc. But all of this comes at the price of complexity. Since your graph is being executed inside its own VM of some sort, you have to have a special way of feeding data into it from the outside, for example from your python program.

This is where placeholders come in. One way of feeding data into your model is to supply it via a feed dictionary when you execute a graph op. And to indicate where inside the graph this data is supposed to go you use placeholders. This way, as Ahmed said, placeholder is a sort of a promise for data supplied in the future. It is literally a placeholder for things you will supply later. To use an example similar to Ahmed's

```
# define graph to do matrix muliplication
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# this is the actual operation we want to do,
# but since we want to supply x and y at runtime
# we will use placeholders
model = tf.matmul(x, y)

# now lets supply the data and run the graph
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    # generate some data for our graph
    data_x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[5, 5])
    data_y = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[5, 5])
    # do the work
    result = session.run(model, feed_dict={x: data_x, y: data_y}
```

There are other ways of supplying data into the graph, but arguably, placeholders and feed_dict is the most comprehensible way and it provides most flexibility.

If you want to avoid placeholders, other ways of supplying data are either loading the whole dataset into constants on graph build or moving the whole process of loading and pre-processing the data into the graph by using input pipelines. You can read up on all of this in the TF documentation.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data